# glassfish how to use one jar file for all application - CDI

Tags: java, glassfish, cdi

Is there possibility to add somewhere in glassfish jar file that can be used with all deployed application? How add it to CLASSPATH?

I've already tried to store jar files in folders:

- domain-dir/lib
- domain-dir/lib/ext
- domain-dir/lib/applibs

I receive an error:

> WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.ClassName
>   because of underlying class loading error: Type com.IClassName not
>   found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full
>   error.]]

I've also make server restart after adding jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a possibility.

Put your lib into `/YOUR_GLASSFISH_INSTALLATION/glassfish/lib`

and restart the server...

Comment: But I can't use CDI @Inject